# how to import react with html5, on react jsx code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The structure is like this -

```
projectname
  css

  html
    foo.html

  reactjsx
    test.jsx

  res
    img
      a.jpg
  ...
```

and in that html file :

```
...
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="../../reactjsx/test.jsx"></script>
...
```

test.jsx is exactly same with :

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hi</h1>, document.getElementById('test'));
```

The problem is that when I open the html file via chrome,
it works perfectly without that import
but it doesn't show 'Hi' with import.
What did I do wrong???

I cannot use import when I am using react and html both????

Comment: Are you loading babel standalone? Also based your structure it should be ../reactjsx/test.jsx

Comment: Sir `@apokryfos`, could you tell me more detail about that? Thank you.    --- oh the html code is right becuz theres a directory under html directory in the actual structure . my html finds right jsx code. so that `<h1>Hi</hi>` works fine , but  i cannot import anything..

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone is required to use `type="text/babel"`